# Error while running profiling report using pandas, giving me an error "TypeError: describe_boolean_1d() got an unexpected keyword argument 'title'"

Tags: pandas

I am using the code below

```
profile = ProfileReport(df, title='Pandas Profiling Report', html={'style':{'full_width':True}})
```

to run a profile report but getting this error

```
"TypeError: describe_boolean_1d() got an unexpected keyword argument 'title'"
```

And when I remove the title, I get this error

```
"TypeError: describe_boolean_1d() got an unexpected keyword argument 'html'"
```

Answer (score 4):

### I got the same error

I run this code in Google Colab:

```
profile = ProfileReport(df, title="Pandas Profiling Report")
```

Then, got the same error. Because, somehow, in Colab, below code to install pandas_profilling didn't work well:

```
pip install pandas-profiling[notebook]
```

Installation by it makes the error.

### Solution

Instead, I use an alternative:

```
pip install https://github.com/pandas-profiling/pandas-profiling/archive/master.zip
```

Then, restart the kernel and done. Errors gone.

Answer (score 3):

I have conda on my machine, so first tried installing pandas-profiling with conda, but had the same error as you.

I have removed it: `conda remove pandas-profiling`
and then reinstall it with pip: `pip install pandas-profiling[notebook,html]`

And it worked fine.

Note: The visualization doesn't work on EDGE browser, Chrome is ok.

Best,
  Victor

Answer (score 1):

3 steps only:

```sh
pip install -U https://github.com/pandas-profiling/pandas-profiling/archive/master.zip

pip install -U pandas-profiling

import pandas_profiling as pp
from pandas_profiling import ProfileReport
```

Source: [Kaggle notebook](https://www.kaggle.com/vbmokin/fe-eda-0-83253-with-pandas-profiling-2-4-2020)